# How to reference this correctly?

Tags: css

I have a CSS like that

```
.rf_re1-submenu ul li.rf_re1-submenu-finder{
background:pink;
}
```

and I want to change some things inside if this block is within a special ID (only then, else the above stuff should be used as default)

I therefore tried that

```
#target-submenu_2block >.rf_re1-submenu ul li.rf_re1-submenu-finder{
background:green;
}
```

But this doesn't work out, neither does this here:

```
#target-submenu_2block ul li.rf_re1-submenu ul li.rf_re1-submenu-finder{
background:green;
}
```

I'd be grateful for your answers for this specific situation but also for a general hint how to solve situations like that.

Comment: Does `#target-submenu_2block .rf_re1-submenu ul li.rf_re1-submenu-finder` work?

Comment: nope, doesn't. And I have no !important-stuff or putting things via js in it

Comment: Show us your HTMl code (one example without the id, one with it) so we can help you. Best way would be to provide one (or two) complete fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
#target-submenu_2block ul li.rf_re1-submenu ul li.rf_re1-submenu-finder
```

to

```
#target-submenu_2block .rf_re1-submenu ul li.rf_re1-submenu-finder
```

Snippet:

```css
.rf_re1-submenu ul li.rf_re1-submenu-finder{
    background:pink;
}

#target-submenu_2block .rf_re1-submenu ul li.rf_re1-submenu-finder{
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>hello
        <ul>
            <li class="rf_re1-submenu-finder">Goodbye</li>
            <li>Goodbye</li>
            <li class="rf_re1-submenu-finder">Goodbye</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li class="rf_re1-submenu">hello
        <ul>
            <li class="rf_re1-submenu-finder">Goodbye</li>
            <li>Goodbye</li>
            <li class="rf_re1-submenu-finder">Goodbye</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul id="target-submenu_2block">
    <li>hello
        <ul>
            <li class="rf_re1-submenu-finder">Goodbye</li>
            <li>Goodbye</li>
            <li class="rf_re1-submenu-finder">Goodbye</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li class="rf_re1-submenu">hello
        <ul>
            <li class="rf_re1-submenu-finder">Goodbye</li>
            <li>Goodbye</li>
            <li class="rf_re1-submenu-finder">Goodbye</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```